# How to use easymotion in visual studio 2015?

Tags: visual-studio-2015, hotkeys

I installed easymotion in visual studio 2015.

Here is the [***source code***](https://github.com/jaredpar/EasyMotion).

I followed those steps and pressed `Shift+Control+;`
However, this is the result on the screen.
How can I use easymotion in vs2015 ?

[image: Why?]

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work in VS2015 because that particular extension is **only for VS2012-2013**.

You can find more information about it on the Visual Studio Marketplace: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=JaredParMSFT.EasyMotion

Comment: I pulled down the source code and have successfully gotten the extension built and running in VS2015, however it is having conflicts with other extensions, such as VsVim. So I'm going to see if I can patch around that, and if I manage to, then I'll upload it to github, cite JaredPar's repo, and post a link here.